# Prove that if all points on a line $m$ are equidistant to a line $n$ then $m \parallel n$

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, euclidean-geometry

I already know how to prove that if $m \parallel n$ then all all points in $m$ are equidistant to $n$. Now I am trying to prove the other way out: if all points on a line $m$ are equidistant to a line $n$ then $m \parallel n$.

This is what I have done so far:

Consider A, B $\in m$ and C,D $\in n$. Consider $P1$ and $P2$ perpendicular lines that intersect $m$ in A and B, and $n$ in C and D, respectively. We have AC and BC perpendicular to $m$, then $AB\parallel CD$, therefore $m\parallel n$

Comment: It is likely that you have the main ideas necessary for a proof, but you need to organize them properly. For example, If you say first $A,B\in m$ and $C,D\in n$, these points have been chosen. So, the lines $P_1$ and $P_2$ could either not be perpendicular to $m$ and $m$ or not pass through some of these points. You could say that $A,B\in m$, then let $P_1,P_2$ be the lines passing through them and perpendicular to $n$ and finally define $C,D$ to be the intersection of $P_1,P_2$ with $n$.

Comment: Instead of "$AC$ and $BC$" I think you mean "$AC$ and $BD$". Also it is not clear how you get from these being perpendicular to $m$, to having $AB || CD$. You should decompose each step into a use of either a theorem or an axiom of your geometry.

Comment: Could you specify what are $P_1$ and $P_2$ perpendicular to?

Comment: Also, assuming that you meant perpendicular to $m$, if you consider $m$ perpendicular to $n$, then all lines perpendicular to $m$ except from one do not intersect with $n$ at all. It is easy to rule out that case though.

Answer (score 1):

your proof is right.
P1 and P2 are equal(same distance), and intersect the other line at 90, hence perpendicular and parallel.
So 4 lines make a parallelogram(rectangle), and the other pair (m&n) must be parallel